# search data related to localstorage item

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux

i m working in simple react todo app. i want to search all items related to email which i saved in local storage on register or login. i m also saved email with todo item.. redux  action to fetch specific todo item is:

````
        return dispatch => {
            dispatch(itemsLoading())
           localStorage.getItem('email')
            const queryParams = '?search=' + createdBy + '&orderBy="register_date"&equalTo="' + register_date + '"';
            axios.get('/api/todos')
                .then(res => {
                console.log(res.data)
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log('error to search')
                    // dispatch(fetchOrderFail(err))
                })
        }
    }```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your axios get request, it looks like you aren't including the query params in the url. You also aren't storing your localStorage request in any way.

I'm not sure about the structure of your query params either, but as a starter, I would restructure your api request like so:

```js
import axios from 'axios'

export const getTodos = () => {
  return dispatch => {
     dispatch(itemsLoading())
     const createdBy = localStorage.getItem('email')
     axios.get(`/api/todos?search=${createdBy}`)
       .then(res => console.log(res))
       .catch(error => console.log(error))
  }
}
```

You'll also probably want to dispatch a success action in your `.then()` handler and a failure action in your `.catch()` handler.

Comment: this can also be done through backend (in mongoose model) by ref keyword. any idea about that?

Comment: If you've saved todos as a ref on the User model (for instance), you would write something like:

```
User.
  findOne({ email: email}).
  populate('todos').
  exec(function (err, user) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);

    return user
  });
```

This is a derivative of the code from the Mongoose docs found here: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#population

You'd want to pull the email from the query params in your http route handler.

Answer (score 0):

The following step you need to do
1. Store it in [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). 
2. you can use filter es6 to filter out data.